# WPF UserControl scrolling unexpectedly inside ElementHost when some contained controls become visible for the first time, but only the first time

Tags: wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

Ok, so...

We have a big hairy WPF UserControl that represents a form the user fills out. It lives inside an ElementHost contained in a WinForms dialog containing a Panel (actually, there are multiple nested panels).  The user control contains elements whose Visibility is set to Collapsed (bound to a boolean DataContext property in which true is converted to Visible and false is converted to Collapsed) when the form initially loads.  Later, when the user control is scrolled down and a checkbox or radio button clicked (with the mouse or with the spacebar), the bound property changes from false to true, and the hidden element(s) become visible.  At this time, something that contains the big user control decides to scroll to (0,0), so everything drops out of sight (i.e., is scrolled below the viewport).

However, if the user scrolls back to where he was and clicks that checkbox a couple of more times (so the visibility on the previously-hidden elements changes back to false and then back to true again), this autoscroll behavior doesn't happen a second time.  It only happens on the first click after the thing is loaded.

This problem doesn't occur when the big user control is not displayed in an ElementHost (actually, because nothing is simple, we have a WinForms dialog that has the ElementHost nested inside it).  We have a "preview mode" that can bring up the big user control just inside its own WPF dialog, no WinForms nonsense.

I've hung SizeChanged, ScrollChanged and RequestBringIntoView event handlers on everything I can see (recursive tree walking), along with handlers for the WinForms Scroll event on every ancestor ScrollableControl up to the root of the tree.  (This thing seems to break Snoop, just to give you an idea of the code base. :) )  No unexpected events seem to occur, but one thing that does happen is that SizeChanged events occur on the hidden elements, as they become visible.  However, when they go back to collapsed and then become visible again, those SizeChanged events don't occur again.

What do I do?  This "form" user control can be a monstrous thing (user-defined), so forcing everything to be visible on load so it can get laid out before hiding things isn't really an option (although I suppose I could try it, just to see if that helps).  Is there some known idiosyncracy with ElementHost, and/or some magic incantation I've missed?

Thanks.